# how to use margin arg with pdftotext.exe

Tags: pdftotext

I am using pdftotext.exe to convert various PDFs into text and need to remove footer, header and marginal annotation.
it is great to see that pdftotext.exe has args such as marginb, margint, marginl and marginr that are meant to remove these bits. here is its documentation.

http://www.xpdfreader.com/pdftotext-man.html

the problem I met is that I can create text out of pdf just using -simple and -layout. however if I add -marginb or others and following numbers. no txt is produced.

pdftotext.exe −layout -marginb 15 -enc UTF-8 D:\pairing\C.PDF

any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm on Linux, but my pdftotext doesn't list -marginb as an option. What do you get with `pdftotext.exe -h`

Comment: HI! Holden, thank you. I am using the latest version 4.02 and under windows,  -h does list -marginb <number> as an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.
For me, the reason was that I copied the option from the command line output.
The minus sign '-' from the command line output is a different character as expected.
After I replaced the minus sign with the standard minus sign, which is on the keyboard, everything worked.
And if I look at your example, you also have 2 different characters.
Try with:

```
pdftotext.exe -layout -marginb 15 -enc UTF-8 D:\pairing\C.PDF
```